# Find the intersection of two strings in order with Scala

Tags: string, list, scala, dictionary, fold

I'm trying to find the intersection of two strings in order with Scala.  I'm pretty new to Scala, but I feel like this should be a one-liner.  I've tried using both map and foldLeft, and have yet to attain the correct answer.

Given two strings, return a list of characters that are the same in order.  For instance, "abcd", "acc" should return "a", and "abcd", "abc" should return "abc".

Here are the two functions I've tried so far

```
(str1 zip str2).map{ case(a, b) => if (a == b) a else ""}
```

and

```
(str1 zip str2).foldLeft(""){case(acc,n) => if (n._1 == n._2) acc+n._1.toString else ""}
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
(str1 zip str2).map{ case(a, b) => if (a == b) a else break}
```

but that doesn't work.

I know that I can do this with multiple lines and a for loop, but this feels like a one liner.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the longest common substring or the longest common prefix?

Comment: Just prefix, for instance "abcd", "bcd" should return ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(str1 zip str2).takeWhile( pair => pair._1 == pair._2).map( _._1).mkString
```

Testing it out in the scala REPL:

```
scala> val str1 = "abcd"
str1: String = abcd

scala> val str2 = "abc"
str2: String = abc

scala> (str1 zip str2).takeWhile( pair => pair._1 == pair._2).map( _._1).mkString
res26: String = abc
```

**Edited** to pass both test cases

```
scala> (str1 zip "acc").takeWhile( pair => pair._1 == pair._2).map( _._1).mkString
res27: String = a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not at all efficient, but it is obvious:

```
 def lcp(str1:String, str2:String) = 
      (str1.inits.toSet intersect str2.inits.toSet).maxBy(_.length)
 lcp("abce", "abcd")                              //> res0: String = abc
 lcp("abcd", "bcd")                               //> res1: String = ""
```

(take the longest of the intersection of all of the prefixes of string 1 with all of the prefixes of string 2)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to avoid zipping the entire strings:

```
(s1, s2).zipped.takeWhile(Function.tupled(_ == _)).unzip._1.mkString
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
scala> val (s1, s2) = ("abcd", "bcd")
s1: String = abcd
s2: String = bcd

scala> Iterator.iterate(s1)(_.init).find(s2.startsWith).get
res1: String = ""

scala> val (s1, s2) = ("abcd", "abc")
s1: String = abcd
s2: String = abc

scala> Iterator.iterate(s1)(_.init).find(s2.startsWith).get
res2: String = abc
```